# PL/PGSQL function, having trouble accessing a returned result set from psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, function, psycopg2

I have this pl/pgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_result(id integer) RETURNS SETOF my_table AS $
    DECLARE
        result_set my_table%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
        IF id=0 THEN
            SELECT INTO result_set my_table_id, my_table_value FROM my_table;
        ELSE
            SELECT INTO result_set my_table_id, my_table_value FROM my_table WHERE my_table_id=id;
        END IF;
        RETURN;
    END;
$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am trying to use this with Python's psycopg2 library.  Here is the python code:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
conn = pg.connect(host='myhost', database='mydatabase', user='user', password='passwd')
cur = conn.cursor()
return cur.execute("SELECT * FROM get_result(0);") # returns NoneType
```

However, if i just do the regular query, I get the correct set of rows back:

```
...
return cur.execute("SELECT my_table_id, my_table_value FROM mytable;") # returns iterable result set
```

Theres obviously something wrong with my pl/pgsql function, but I can't seem to get it right.

I also tried using

```
RETURN result_set;
```

instead of just

```
RETURN
```

in the 10th line of my plpgsql function, but got an error from postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the error you're getting when you change "RETURN;" to "RETURN result_set;". And then read the following - ["38.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN47541).

A hint - in your case you need "RETURN QUERY".

Comment: Thanks a lot, I remember seeing the RETURN QUERY statement earlier, but didn't think it was right.  That did the trick though, so thanks!